# Usage of hiltViewModel() and createComposeRule() in robolectric's test is throwing NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, robolectric, dagger-hilt

I run following test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class ExampleTest {
    @get:Rule
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun test() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            hiltViewModel<ExampleViewModel>()
        }
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(context: Context) : ViewModel()
```

Inside `composeTestRule.setContent` i call `hiltViewModel<ExampleViewModel>()` which is part of `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03` artifact.

Unfortunately this test is throwing `NoSuchMethodException` while initialising viewModel.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.ExampleViewModel.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    ... 115 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix that problem we have to use:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<HiltActivity>()
```

instead of

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()
```

where **HiltActivity** is activity with `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation from dagger hilt.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HiltActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work since createAndroidComposeRule requires *ComponentActivity* and won't accept *CompatAppActvitiy*